# how to display next image selected by file chooser next time

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, imageicon, filechooser

How to display next image selected by file chooser next time
 This is my code that had a filechooser to choose file and display the image on jlabel.
 The image is scaled to proper size correctly but when i try to choose next or other 
 image file through filechooser..the new image did not displayed out..previous image
 stills there..not able to display the updated image..
 I have also set the path name of image in the textfield and it gets set
 correctly.but the image is not updated on jlabel...

please any one tell me where is
 my code wrong..

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser jFileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();
    repaint();

    jFileChooser1.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int state = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();

    if (state == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
        s2 = file.toString();
        jTextField1.setText(s2);

        jLabel1.setName(s2);
        jLabel1.setLocation(40, 40);
        jLabel1.setSize(300, 300);
        jLabel1.setVisible(true);
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(file);
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),file.getName());
            icon = new ImageIcon(bi);

            Image img = icon.getImage();
            icon = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
            // icon = new ImageIcon(paths[currentIndex].getPath());
            scaleImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(80, 80,
                    Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

            resizedImage = resize(bi, 200, 200);
            icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);

            jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
            jLabel2 = new JLabel();

            repaint();
            pack();

            paths = file.getParentFile().listFiles();
            currentIndex = indexOf(paths, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } else if (state == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Canceled");
    }
    add(jLabel1);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't recreate jLabel1. Store it somewhere as a field of the class and just call setIcon() passing image from the file chooser